# Doubts WITH Epics On TFS

Tags: tfs

How can I see the Epic related with the user story on the own user story?

Is there option on TFS of Microsoft?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's detail related are you talking about? Did you mean you want to see the epics for a specific user story?

Answer (score 1):

Epics are hierarchically above Features. Features are mapped to Epics, like user story items are mapped to Features.

[image]

There is no way to directly see the Epic through the own user story itself. However, as a workaround, you can LINK work items and you can display them as a Tree List,see it through a backlog.

[image]

Also have a check of this link for further information on how to use TFS to support epics, release trains, and multiple backlogs: [Implement Scaled Agile Framework® to support epics, release trains, and multiple backlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/scaled-agile-framework)